Name of that 70's-80's movie where young people in power that killed old people
I would like to have the name of a movie where young people take control of US  and decided that as soon as you are older you not worth anything thus they kill them or sent somewhere. I remember that old people hide and also they are given LSD, or government give LSD to people.The movie is American from the 70's or 80's. My memories are blury I hope my description will ring bells to anybody. 

Reminds a little bit of logans run, where everybody has to die on his 30 birthday, but the rest of your description does not fit...

Wild In The Streets
This bit of counter-culture silliness includes young people taking over the world and sending over 35s off to LSD-fueled camps to keep them under control.

Actually the movie is "Wild in the Streets" 18 year olds are allowed to run for congress etc. The President is like 21. Older people are herded into concentration camps after 30yeas and forced to take LSD
The "Presidents" mother tries to hide her age, but eventually put in the concentration camp.
The Main Song in the movie is called "Nothing can change the shape of things to come"
The movie ends with

 The president is out and upsets a kid (don't remember exactly what he did) and the kid says.."We're gonna put everyone over 18 out of business"


You may be mixing Logan's Run and Soylent Green. People over 30 die in LR. In SG the old check into sort of death centers, get pumped full of drugs & something to kill them, and drift off watching a gorgeous technicolor film about how pretty the world used to be.
